# No electric in my garage

Tags: electrical, grounding

My electricity in my garage went out recently. The UF wires are buried righht next to a large tree, so im assuming the roots had something to do with it. Well it rained for 2 days straight and my lights came on, so im thinking the water is acting a the connector. I dug a section of it up and it was a metal pipie with a white wire running along the side. In the garage theres a pipe that comes up and has 2 black wires(romex) and a white UF. Im thinking black is hot,nuetral and white is ground. My question is its probaly the ground thats cut by the tree so can i just get a new grounding rod for next to the garage and cut at house and pull up the bad one? Thanks in advace.

Comment: We're going to need more information.  Is there a single circuit in the garage, or an electrical panel?  What do the wires coming into the garage connect to, and how do they connect?

Comment: Is there a switch that controls the power to the garage?  Perhaps someone turned it off and on without your knowing.  Rain water is a poor conductor, so it is not likely to close an open circuit.  Rain could cause wood to swell.  Is the wiring to the lights solid or might small movements cause an open circuit?

Comment: This isn't really an answer (see Tester101's reply), so I'll put it here - it's very unlikely that the white wire is your ground and causing the problem unless something has ground-faulted in the garage. If this is the case, everything metal could/would be energized. The ground will not affect power to your system but has to be wired back to it's source. Ground rods do almost nothing for ground fault. Cut power to the subpanel and then check in the main and sub to ensure which wires feed what.

Comment: Pictures would help this question. If the wire is in conduit it's actually not all that likely that the tree (or the rain) has anything to do with it. If the wires are aluminum and especially if they were non-professionally installed, I'd start with suspecting and checking the connections first and foremost. Likely do that with copper as well, but poorly installed aluminum is the classic version of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No. While ground may be tied to the earth, it's also connected back to the source (distribution transformer).  Electricity doesn't flow from the transformer to the earth, it flows from the transformer back to the transformer.

Only connecting the grounding conductor to the earth, will not provide an effective ground-fault path.  So a ground-fault will not trip the breaker, as it should.

Without more information, it's difficult to tell exactly what's going on with your installation. My recommendation would be to contact a local licensed Electrician, unless you have the tools and knowledge to troubleshoot the problem yourself.